# smooch - "continuing conversation" notifications

Tags: smooch

I recently set up smooch on slack but am only receiving notifications when new users start conversations, not when returning customers continue a conversation as outlined [here](http://blog.smooch.io/live-chat-vs-new-live-chat-what-this-means-for-customer-service/)

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

in order to receive a "User continued the conversation..." notifications in your configured dispatch channel the existing user's `#sk-user` channel itself must have been archived. You can manually archive channels with the `/archive` command, or from the Smooch Slack config page you can configure channels to be automatically archived after a configurable period of inactivity.

(Note that the auto-archive won't archive a channel where the user had the last word, to make sure you don't miss any follow-up comments)

Comment: Thanks. I set up the time to 1hr on the Smooch Slack config page and answered the user, but 4 hrs later the channel is still not archived. What's going on there?

Comment: Hmm can you shoot us an email at hello@smooch.io